# How to pass a parameter to a function with SoapClient?

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

Unfortunately, I don't have any SOAP experience, please excuse me eventually using wrong notation below -

I have been given 2 URLs and an XML string and I am trying to get an XML-response from a remote SOAP server.

The 1st URL is an WSDL document, I feed it to the [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/de/class.soapclient.php) constructor:

```
$client = new SoapClient(URL_1, array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0));
```

And the 2nd URL is the SOAP server, I use it here:

```
$client->__setLocation(URL_2);
```

This works well and I am able to retrieve the *types* and *functions* with:

```
print_r( $client->__getTypes() );
print_r( $client->__getFunctions() );
```

Here is interesting part of the output:

```
[28] => struct GetServiceInfo {
 UserAuthentification UserAuthentification;
}

[74] => struct UserAuthentification {
 string UserId;
 string Password;
 string SessionKey;
}

[3] => GetServiceInfoResponse GetServiceInfo(GetServiceInfo $parameters)
```

**My problem** is to call the above `GetServiceInfo` *function*.

I have been given this XML string which works well with [SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org/) program:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://...../V1">
  <soap:Header>.....</soap:Header>   
  <soap:Body>
      <v1:GetServiceInfo>
         <UserAuthentification>
            <UserId>MY_USERNAME</UserId>
            <Password>MY_PASSWORD</Password>
          </UserAuthentification>
      </v1:GetServiceInfo>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I pass this parameter in my PHP script please?

I have tried:

```
$result = $client->GetServiceInfo(array(
        new SoapParam( "UserAuthentification", array(   # ERROR, WANTS STRING HERE
        new SoapParam( "UserId", "MY_USERNAME" ),
        new SoapParam( "Password", "MY_PASSWORD" ),
)))); 

var_dump( $client->__getLastRequest() );
var_dump( $client->__getLastResponse() );

print_r( $result );
```

But get the error:

```
Warning: SoapParam::SoapParam() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in soap.php

Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'UserAuthentification' property in soap.php
```

I think I am missing something minor here, please help.

**UPDATE:**

I have come further with the following step:

```
$user = array('UserId' => 'MY_USERNAME', 'Password' => 'MY_PASSWORD');
$params = array('UserAuthentification' => $user);
$result = $client->GetServiceInfo($params);
```

Now I get the error:

> [FaultDescription] => Unable to identify service
>
> [FaultReason] => wsa:To is missing and the given URL /services could
>   not be mapped to an existing service

Comment: Thank you, I've passed your suggestion to my colleague, don't have much time for this task myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server uses WS-Addressing (as evidenced by the FaultReason - keyword is `wsa:To`) which is not supported by the regular PHP SoapClient extension.

I have yet to use WS-Addressing but I was recently analysing an API for project we will be working on in the future that requires it.

Please take note of [this project](https://github.com/coopTilleuls/wse-php) or [this other project](https://github.com/robrichards/wse-php) which may be useful (it's easy to search for more `PHP WS-Addressing`). Again, I have only done research and do not have any hands-on experience to help you with actual code :)